# How to get images going over navigation bar?

Tags: jquery, html, css

here is the example where you can see it. http://www.spine-practice.com/index.php
As you can see the pictures are transitioning (know how to do this) but what I want to know is how is it made so that the images are going over the navigation bar?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use an absolutely positioned div (as the site you mentioned does).

When using `position: absolute` in the CSS the element won't be put in the normal flow and instead put on top of other elements if they overlap (assuming they are in the same z-index layer).

Here's an example:

```
.overlay{
    height: 200px;
    position: absolute;
    top: 50px;
    left: 200px;
    width: 100px;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/xEa7G/

Answer (score 0):

It's just with `z-index`. If you watch source code, he plays with `position:absolute` and z-index to superimpose element.

Read this document : http://html.net/tutorials/css/lesson15.php